# How do I have a gravel kit certified as an STC?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, stc

Any idea how one certifies a gravel kit for an aircraft? I am interested in possibly developing and certifying a gravel kit as an STC.

I am looking for FAA regulations that would be involved in such a project.

Comment: Are you wanting to do a one time field approved alteration for one certified aircraft, develop your own Supplemental Type Certificate alteration for certified aircraft, or something else entirely?

Comment: I'd contact a Flight Standards District office in your local area about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FAA has a [nice checklist here](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/stc/stc_app/).

You should read through the FAA's [GUIDE FOR OBTAINING A SUPPLEMENTAL TYPE CERTIFICATE](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_21-40A.pdf). I assume you are a civilian but,

> This advisory circular (AC) is a certification guide for obtaining a
>   supplemental type certificate (STC). It is intended for civilian
>   applicants only. We have written it to help designers, manufacturers
>   and installers applying for STCs to better understand the STC process.
>   The guidance in this AC is general in nature and intended to help an
>   applicant gain a basic understanding of the STC process and our
>   respective roles and responsibilities.

You will need to fill out [this application form](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/811012v3_with_instructions_AS_6_19_14_PRA_revised.pdf) and submit it to the FAA ACO office in your area.